# Auto download birt report in xlsx

Tags: java, xlsx, birt

I developed a BIRT report and it's working fine, but when I open an HTML preview screen and there I can export it to different formats, I want when people run or report it automatically download in Excel format (xlsx), I've seen several types and I got to java code, but it's got some errors (in the part of opening the report) and I'm also not sure how to reference that java code in my report (.rptdesign). Could you help me perform this automatic export process?
Thanks!

public class EXCELRenderOption extends RenderOption{

```
// Open report design
IReportRunnable design = BidiLine.openReportDesign(sc.getRealPath("/report/") + reportName + ".rptdesign");

ReportDesign report = (ReportDesignHandle) design.getDesignHandle();

// create task to run and render report
task = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);

res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "xcel.xls" + "\"");
EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();
options.setOutputFormat("xlsx");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.xlsx");

options.setOutputFileName("corporate-batches-summary-report.xlsx");
options.setOutputStream(res.getOutputStream());
task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();
task.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to build a jar of your java codes with all dependencies. Then use birt's scripted data source and scripted data set where during open your intended class should be called.